# Как получить параметры окружения, переданные программе?

Tags: python, c

Как вывести параметры среды, переданные программе, на python или C?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473692/list-environment-variables-with-c-in-unix

Comment: [man environ](https://linux.die.net/man/7/environ)

Answer (score 2):

Расскажу только о C.

Если конкретная переменная нужна - то есть стандартная [`getenv()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv).

Если нужен список всех переменных - то можно воспользоваться (если компилятор поддерживает POSIX) - предопределенной переменной [`environ`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08). Но есть и второй вариант - получить доступ к этой же переменной из функции `main`, если ее объявить как

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[], char * env[])
```

Тоже вроде бы не совсем стандарт, но пока не встречал компилятора, который бы такое не поддерживал. Visual C++ поддерживает, [GNU поддерживает](http://ideone.com/m8wys4).

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

P.S. Просто приколоться:

```
system("set");
```

Answer (score 2):

Раз Harry был так добр, что написал ответ для C, то дополню ответом для Python.

```
import os

# Для вывода конкретной переменной окружения
print(os.environ['PATH'])

# Для вывода всех переменных окружения
for name, value in os.environ.items():
    print(name, value)
```